# How can I make a block only be placed on certain other blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want people to only be able to place TNT on only Quartz Blocks and I've see this done before where you can only place blocks on certain other blocks but I'm not sure of the command used to do that.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_Format#Block_Tags), about Item NBT tags :

> Blocks can be given tags to specify what blocks they may be placed
> against in Adventure mode [...]
>
> **tag**: The tag tag.
>
> - **CanPlaceOn**: Determines which blocks that blocks with this tag can be
>   placed against in adventure mode.

As the `give` command takes the Item's `tag` tag as last parameter, you just have to drop your list of blocks in there :

```
// Give one block of stone that can be placed on grass or dirt
give @p minecraft:stone 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:grass","minecraft:dirt"]}
```

Or, in 1.13+:

```
give @p stone{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:grass","minecraft:dirt"]}
```

Comment: The question has been asked 4 hours ago and you beat me by 1 minute ;)

Comment: I know that but I need to know the command.                  **/give [player] [item] [DataValue] [Amount] [Something]**         The something refers to the part I don't know which is where the syntax is and that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @FireStrike289 Edited. The syntax is JSON. By the way, be cautious as `give`'s data and amount parameters are the other way around :)

Comment: I understand the part above, but can you put block variants into the {CanPlaceOn:[id: ... ]} part? And if so, how? I've already tried experimenting with the code, but I can figure it out :/

Comment: @SMILIECHICKEN apparently you can't, or at least it's not mentioned in the wiki.

Comment: @pppery thanks, I incorporated it :)

Answer (score 2):

Type this in commands:

```
/give (your name) minecraft:TNT 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:quartz_block"]}
```

IMPORTANT:
You can change

```
minecraft:TNT 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:quartzblock"]}
```

to whatever you like.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `give (your name) minecraft:TNT{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:quartz_block"]}`

Answer (score 0):

**Lever that you can place on diamond block!** Can be used in Custom/Puzzle-Map!
`/give [Username] lever 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:diamond_block"]}`

That is a lever that you can place on diamond block! You can change it!:

`/give [Username] [block] 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:**[Your block]**"]}`

Or can place on more blocks!

`/give [Username] [block] 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:[Your block],minecraft:[2nd block]"]}`

Comment: While nice on it's own, this answer doesn't really add anything either of the previous two answers have omitted.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `give [Username] [block]{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:[Your block]",'minecraft:[2nd block]"]}`