# What is the command to get block that you can place it in gamemode 2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I get a block like a pressure plate, that allows me to place it in Adventure Mode (gamemode 2), because you can't normally place blocks?

Comment: [Search is your friend...](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191628/how-can-i-make-a-block-only-be-placed-on-certain-other-blocks)

Comment: If anything here in the answers helped you, feel free to mark one as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

> /give @p stone 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:grass","minecraft:dirt"]}

This command give 1 (1, next to stone) of selected block (stone) to the closest player (@p), and can be placed on Grass and dirt. This needs Minecraft 1.8, to use it in pre-1.8, replace item names with their respective numbers.

Answer (score 0):

[Wiki page 1](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Adventure)

[Wiki page 2](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_NBT_Tags)

For such commands as /summon and /setblock, place them inside of a `tag` tag, like so: `{id:"stone",Count:3 ... tag:{Name:"CanPlaceOn" ...}}`

If you are making a player place it down use

```
/give minecraft:YourBlockNameHere {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:YourBlockNameHere","minecraft:YourBlockNameHere"]}
```

for one placeable block

```
/give minecraft:YourBlockNameHere {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:YourBlockNameHere"]}
```

Anyone please suggest edits. I'm very bad at explaining things

Comment: place them inside of a tag tag? what what do do you you mean mean?

Comment: tag:{Name: <-like that

Comment: It's not a variable. Minecraft doesn't have real variables, the closest you can get to it are scoreboards. That doesn't have much to do with NBT. "tag tag" is actually correct here and to emphasise what it means, I've marked the first "tag" to make clear that it's the NBT key.