# Make a blocks placeable on any blocks in adventure mode with shorter command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I and my friend are making a bedwars map in 1.12.2 . We decided to use adventure mode when play to prevent other players destroy the map , but still have some problem. The tools will use to break specific blocks, that's fine but placing blocks would be a problem. The map built by such a lots of different blocks, so if i make a wool blocks placeable on all of other blocks, i need to make a long, really long command such like [Is there a way to make a block placeable on any block in adventure mode?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/260872/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-block-placeable-on-any-block-in-adventure-mode). So, i'm wondering that: any more ways to do that but shorter command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no shorter command. But that doesn't matter, because you can just copy-paste the list from my other answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/351979/171580). The list also works in 1.12, because the newer blocks will just be ignored. You just need to adjust the first part of the command.

Comment: So, ok. It looks like all-in-one command. Thanks