# How to make it to where players can place a lever on a certain block? Adventure Mode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am creating an adventure map and I need the player to be able to place levers on gold blocks. How can I do this via command block?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question.

Comment: Whoops - Added a close vote on the wrong question. Someone will have to start another. It's [How can I make a block only be placed on certain other blocks?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191628/how-can-i-make-a-block-only-be-placed-on-certain-other-blocks?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the `CanPlaceOn` NBT tag attached to the item.

```
/give @p minecraft:Lever 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:gold_block"]}
```