# How do I allow placement of minecarts on powered rails in adventure mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm running Minecraft 1.15.2 on an Aternos server (free server website) and I'm trying to figure out how to allow players to place minecarts on rails while in adventure mode.

Does anyone happen to know the full command for that? Especially one that works on Aternos.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a block only be placed on certain other blocks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191628/how-can-i-make-a-block-only-be-placed-on-certain-other-blocks)

Answer (score 1):

`/give [player] minecart{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:powered_rail"]}`