# Place a lever on only emerald blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've done this before, but I have forgotten how to do it. I tried every command but nothing is working, and I was trying to be quick. Is there a way to do this in Minecraft 1.16?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Could you please specify what you are needing, and perhaps show the outcome that was closest to your expected result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a block only be placed on certain other blocks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191628/how-can-i-make-a-block-only-be-placed-on-certain-other-blocks)

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'CanPlaceOn' NBT/component with the give command to give you levers which are only allowed to be placed on emerald blocks when the player is in Adventure mode.

Java:

```
/give @s minecraft:lever{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:emerald_block"]} 64
```

Bedrock:

```
/give @s lever 64 0 {"can_place_on":{"blocks":["emerald_block"]}}
```

You can't restrict them if they are in either Survival or Creative mode.