# How do I give myself blocks that can only be placed on red wool?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

All wool blocks use the `minecraft:wool` tag. Does anyone know how a solution?

So far I only have this:

```
/give @a minecraft:stained_hardened_clay 5 9 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:wool"]}
```

Comment: Isn't `minecraft:red_wool` a thing though?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a block only be placed on certain other blocks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191628/how-can-i-make-a-block-only-be-placed-on-certain-other-blocks)

Comment: Furthermore, you can change command in the above post to suit your needs, like using the argument `minecraft:red_wool`. Another thing to note in your command: _/give @a minecraft:stained_hardened_clay 5 9 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:wool"]}_ : Avoid spacing between "9" and "{". Minecraft takes small matters seriously. Also, why is there a spacing between "5" and "9"? Do you mean "59"? If so, again, remove spacing otherwise MC will give error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command you need to write.

```
/give @a minecraft:stained_hardened_clay 5 9 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:red_wool"]}
```

Or writing it in 1.13+ looks like:

```
/give @a stained_hardened_clay{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:red_wool"]}
```

I saw a comment that said you needed to write it like `59` with no space, that is incorrect you need the space, so when you write it would look like this: `5 9`.

Comment: you also need to put the person in adventure mode