# Whats the right command to make a certain item placeable on specific blocks?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

I am trying to make a ladder only placeable on a certain block but I always get a syntax error, or a unexpected bracket. I even copied the command completely straight and exactly the same but it still does not work.

I've tried from multiple sources using different but similar commands but it always gives me the same feedback

The command I've tried is /give @p ladder 1 0 {"minecraft:can_place_on":{"blocks"'["polished_Blackstone_bricks"]]}

I play minecraft on the Nintendo Switch if this helps.

Comment: Please don't repost questions. You can edit your older posts to update them.

Comment: The reason why it doesn't work is because you have an extra square bracket instead of a second curly bracket, `Blackstone` is uppercase and you're also missing a colon (":"). So, change the command to: `/give @p ladder 1 0 {"minecraft:can_place_on":{"blocks":'["polished_blackstone_bricks"]'}}`.

Answer (score -1):

As [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191628/how-can-i-make-a-block-only-be-placed-on-certain-other-blocks/191637#191637) suggests, I think you can use the command

```
/give @p minecraft:lever 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:diamond_block"]}
```

Comment: Do NBT tags work for Bedrock edition? Because that question was asked for Java.

Comment: Yeah! it is impossible to add NBT tags in Bedrock Edition. So, sorry.